# Replacing a lock with an interlocked operation

Tags: c#, .net, locking, interlocked

Is there anyway of replacing this code using the `Interlocked.Exchange` API?

```
if (IsWorking == false)
{
    lock (this)
    {
        if (IsWorking == false)
        {
            IsWorking = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have a double check lock to assign a boolean?

Comment: Such a bool almost always should be a Auto/ManualResetEvent instead.  Which gets rid of the lock.

Comment: As a side note, it's generally a BAD idea to lock on `this`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but whether it would be useful is another matter.

You could replace `isWorking` with an integer, and then use `Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref isWorking, 1, 0)`.

This is pointless though; either way the result at the end is that `isWorking` is `1`, so we would have better concurrency by just replacing the code with `IsWorking = true` (or perhaps a `VolatileWrite` to ensure it was seen by other CPUs).

Your code is probably a reduction of something like:

```
if (isWorking == false)
    lock (this)
        if (isWorking == false)
        {
            DoSomethingWorthDoing();
            isWorking = true;
        }
```

And it's the `DoSomethingWorthDoing()` part that falls down.

There are ways of improving the concurrency of such double-checked locks, but it depends on a few things. One example is:

```
if(someUsefulThing == null)
  Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref someUsefulThing, SomeUsefulFactory(), null);
```

At the end of this `someUsefulThing` will be set to the result of `SomeUsefulFactory()`, and after being set it will not be set again. There will though be a period in which we might call `SomeUsefulFactory()` multiple times just to throw the result away. Sometimes that's a disaster, sometimes that's fine, and sometimes we could have just done no locking and been fine; it depends on just why we're concerned to share the same object here.

There are further variants, but applicability depends on just why you care about concurrency. [This code](https://bitbucket.org/JonHanna/ariadne/src/e4e6580d40f58c48feea8ff90436afce745f5975/Ariadne/Collections/ThreadSafeDictionary.cs?at=master), for example, implements a thread-safe concurrent dictionary using such interlocked operations, which tends to be slower than just putting a `lock` around accessing a dictionary when contention is low, but much better when many threads access it at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

You would usually use `Interlocked.CompareExchange` to do that. But unfortunatley there isn't an overload that accepts a boolean and the `object` and generic overloads work only on reference types. You can however hack that and use an `int` with only 2 values (0 and 1):

```
private static int IsWorking = 0;
private static void Main()
{
    var originalValue = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref IsWorking, 1, 0);
}
```

`Interlocked.CompareExchange`, as the name suggest, compares 2 values (`IsWorking` and 0) and if they are equal stores the other value (1) in the original location. The return value is what used to be in the original location before invoking this atomic method. So if a 0 was returned the call replaced the value in `IsWorking` and if it's 1 then a different thread got there first.

About [`Interlocked.CompareExchange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/801kt583(v=vs.110).aspx):

> "If comparand and the value in location1 are equal, then value is stored in location1. Otherwise, no operation is performed. The compare and exchange operations are performed as an atomic operation. The return value of CompareExchange is the original value in location1, whether or not the exchange takes place."

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `IsWorking = true` would be equivalent unless there is other concurrent code that is holding the lock when this executes. Assignments of primitve values like that are guaranteed to be atomic. Clearly the combination of the conditional and the assigment might not be atomic. However, it appears that the code wants to set IsWorking to true only if IsWorking is now false. However, if IsWorking is now true, what would be the harm in re-setting it to True? It seems like you're missing something that wants a thread-safe way to notify the outside world of a state change. This is where you might use an Event or a Monitor.

You might also be looking for `Interlocked.CompareExchange` but that will only work for reference types and primitive numeric types. So you would need to change from a boolean to an int for example. However, the CompareExchange method won't wait as your lock will. It will simply return the old value regardless of whether it was replaced or not.

So if you changed IsWorking from a boolean property to an int field, you could:

```
int wasWorking = Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref isWorking, 1, 0);
```

if wasWorking is 0, you know you changed the state, if wasWorking is 1, you know you didn't change the state.